# How to unit test data based on current week days

Tags: ios, unit-testing

So I have some items added to Core Data which contains a `Date` field. I have a method which retrieves all data from the current week.
My questions is how can I unit test this ?

The given data should always work when tested. It should not be depended on the day the test run.

For example right now my data looks like this:

```
 // Given
 1. add item with Date = today
 2. add item with Date = today - 1
 3. add item with Date = today - 4

 // When
 Get items count

 // Then
 XCTAssertTrue(count == 3)
```

This will work when the unit test is run on Friday, Saturday or Sunday. But if I run it today it will fail.

What is the easiest way to test this scenario ?

Comment: Create a proxy object that forges data for your tests.

Comment: Or someway to feed custom data to your tests.

Comment: Can you provide an example ? Is not that clear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, don't let your unit tests get their data from a real "service". Mock out the service that gives you the data that you are testing here. Replace it with a dumb implementation of the real service and hard code the data it returns. Then you don't have to worry about weekdays and stuff.